# Thread.Wait() exception, not knowing how to fix it

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an frameAnimation, i only want it to start for like 3 second or so...therefore i added in a thread to wait for 3 second but then i meet an exception.

im havent done any work with thread before so this is pretty much my first time using it, can anyone help?

this is my code:

```
    public void setTimerImage4Bot() throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread();

    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =    (AnimationDrawable)bot.getDrawable();
    frameAnimation.setCallback(bot);
    frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
    frameAnimation.start();
    Log.i("BaoAnh","START");
    thread.wait(3000);
    frameAnimation.stop();
    Log.i("BaoAnh","STOP");
    generateRandom();

    }
```

this is the error:

```
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at com.example.PaperCissorsRock.game.setTimerImage4Bot(game.java:63)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at com.example.PaperCissorsRock.game$1.onClick(game.java:44)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 10:11:55.633: WARN/System.err(740): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-21 10:11:55.643: WARN/System.err(740): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 10:11:55.643: WARN/System.err(740): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-21 10:11:55.643: WARN/System.err(740): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-21 10:11:55.643: WARN/System.err(740): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-21 10:11:55.643: WARN/System.err(740): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to wrap `Thread#wait()` inside a `synchronized` block.

Comment: synchronized block? do you have an exmaple please? :(..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Thread.sleep(3000);`

But You better use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method also. By using postDelayed you can perform a runnable task after an interval

For example

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       do tasks which will be done after 3 seconds
   } 
},3000);
```

Comment: if i use sleep it will freeze the whole apps for 3second...so my animation would not work :(

Comment: better use postdelyaed @zBaoAnhLe

Comment: yeah do u have any example for postDelayed please?...sorry to bother you

Comment: yes i tried your code...it worked!...but..problem...it only work once :(...i tap the button again and nothing happen :(

Comment: it is a single time task. place this codes in button's onClick method. so that when you click the button then it will run. for further problem update your question with new codes

Answer (score 0):

The `wait` method is for object synchronisation. If you just want to sleep for a bit, use `sleep`.

> **Object**
>
> **public final void wait (long millis)**
>
> Causes the calling thread to wait until another thread calls the notify() or notifyAll() method of this object or until the specified timeout expires. **This method can only be invoked by a thread which owns this object's monitor;** see notify() on how a thread can become the owner of a monitor.

You're getting the error because you're not the owner of the monitor, nor should you be since waiting on the object is not what you want to do.

And keep in mind that `sleep` is a static function, you don't need to instantiate a thread object to use it. Just use:

```
Thread.sleep (3000);
```